# I need a camera with specific needs. And I hate cameras

Tags: video, camera-recommendation

As much as I love technology, I'm not really into cameras. So I've been looking for a camera to record a YouTube show with, for two hours now; I give up, I can't take it anymore.

Here are the desired specs (just please list me options and I'll choose myself after evaluating. So this isn't an opinionated post to be removed hopefully. I have very specific needs to meet):

1- Records 1920x1080 progressive full HD. (Good sensor, please. Not making a theater movie here, but something decent with no excessive blur or very off colors. I'll set up a white well-lit pseudo-studio in my room, with greenscreen background).

2- Accepts standard tripod mount (the little female screw hole in the camera to meet the male screw of the tripod).

3- Accepts 3.5mm Microphone extension.

4- Price needs to be < $200. $250 at most. Just starting out with VERY tight budget.

Bonus: Preferably small to reduce shipping costs internationally, although I'd manage with any size if it meets the criteria.

Comment: You hate cameras, huh? What're you doing here?

Answer (score 2):

Check out the Canon EOS M.
this was a $600+ mirrorless camera but recently, reduced to $249 on Amazon.

I have one as a backup, and it is simply amazing at video. Has the resolution plus the mic input and 1080p @24ps  for that cinema look. The quality is equal to cameras costing 10x as much.

Totally amazing!

This link maybe of interest http://youtu.be/eBCZOqHJ5QQ

Comment: Why would this answer be downvoted (without a matching comment)? It seems to be a direct answer that fits the requirement.

Comment: It was down voted because the question was video related and not still Photography related. In hindsight, I should not have responded to it but as I had recently purchased the EOS M, I got a little excited as I have been using for the same purposes as the original Poster and I knew it was a direct fit ... I'll know for next time :)

Comment: I know the question might be off topic, but why penalize the *answer*?

Comment: My guess is that it is like a little penalty to ensure it doesn't happen.

Comment: That's cruel and insensitive.